# Preserving color of Image Icons in flutter

Tags: android, flutter

I am trying to an image as icon. I am able to set the image as icon but the only problem is that the image is getting decolorized. I don't want the image to get decolorized. I want the image to appear as it is. So is there a way to preserve the color of the image used as image icon in flutter?

Comment: What are you trying to do here. I don't get the question.

Comment: When you add image icons in the list tile they get decolorized. The lose their original color. But I want my icons to appear with the original colors. So my question was how to do that.

Comment: Can you use a CircleAvatar?

Comment: @RainerWittmann your solution worked but i m not able to increase the size of cicrcle avatar in the expansion panel. Can u please help me. I tried increasing the radius but didn't work

Answer (score 5):

This isn't possible with `ImageIcon` because the `IconThemeData` color will default to black and your image will be recolored. I would just use an `Image` widget instead, e.g.

```
return new Image(
  image: image,
  width: iconSize,
  height: iconSize,
  fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
  alignment: FractionalOffset.center
);
```

Also, note that you may want to position your `Image` with a layout widget such as `Center`, `Row`, etc.